# How to connect to sybase IQ server using a Java application

Tags: java, sap-iq

I have a Java application which needs to read data from sybase IQ server.

How can I connect directly to Sybase IQ to collect my data?

Is it possible to make a connection by using the jdbc drivers of IQ?

Are there any limitations or restrictions to do so from a Java application?

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of two Sybase JDBC drivers: either jConnect (TDS-protocol-based) or the native SQL Anywhere driver (CmdSeq-protocol-based) (IQ uses SQL Anywhere inside for various things, including connectivity). 
Both are full-featured JDBC drivers; with jConnect, you can also connect to Sybase ASE databases.
Note that there are some differences in the default session settings depending on which JDBC driver you connect with. This is the same issue as when using a TDS-based client like ASE's 'isql' vs. native SQL Anywhere clients like 'dbisql'.

More info:

jConnect: 
http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/23450/jconnect-software-developer-kit-download

Native SA driver:
http://scn.sap.com/community/sql-anywhere/blog/2014/05/02/connecting-to-sql-anywhere-using-jdbc